# Hyperledger Fabric Peer Certificates and Keyfiles

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Can anyone help me understand what are the purpose of each of these files? I am having trouble understanding the documentation.

For `basic-network` in path `basic-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com` we have these files

```
peer0.org2.example.com
├── msp
│   ├── admincerts
│   │   └── Admin@org2.example.com-cert.pem
│   ├── cacerts
│   │   └── ca.org2.example.com-cert.pem
│   ├── keystore
│   │   └── 0d9f72608133ee627b570b6af6877666bc8f365746f9329d6dd8a5f54e53e2ab_sk
│   ├── signcerts
│   │   └── peer0.org2.example.com-cert.pem
│   └── tlscacerts
│       └── tlsca.org2.example.com-cert.pem
└── tls
    ├── ca.crt
    ├── server.crt
    └── server.key 
8 directories, 8 files
```

What is the purpose of these files, what files/certificates are used in sdk that connects to this particular peer (peer0.org2.example.com).
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

Each Organization requires a unique root certificate (ca-cert), that binds specific components (peers and orderers) to that organization.

Transactions and communications within Fabric are signed by an entity's private key (keystore), and then verified by means of a public key (signcerts).

As different organization also required to communicate or share their ledger so there is need of CA or MSP on organization level. Within each organization we can have multiple peers so we need certification for these peers too. Even peers from different organizations can join each other so signcerts(for authenticating) and TLScerts(for a secure handshake).

To have a look how these are generate i suggest you to Manually generate the artifacts

http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html

and see the different certs in the folders inside as you created them.